# Authentication of Username Password Token Failed - Calling SOAP Service in Postman

Tags: java, rest, authentication, soap, postman

I'm trying to call a SOAP Webservice using POSTMAN with below XML Body. Upon calling it via POSTMAN I'm getting authentication issue:

```xml
xmlns:niec="http://www.xxxxxxx.com/ws/xxxxxxxCustservice/v1/xxxxxxxCustLookup"
    xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"
    xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
    <soapenv:Header>
        <wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="1">
            <wsse:UsernameToken>
                <wsse:Username>username</wsse:Username>
                <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordDigest">password</wsse:Password>
                <wsse:Nonce>ZHNoYmFzZGE5OA==</wsse:Nonce>
                <wsu:Created>2024-02-01T14:07:00Z</wsu:Created>
            </wsse:UsernameToken>
            <wsu:Timestamp>
                <wsu:Created>2024-02-02T14:16:00Z</wsu:Created>
                <wsu:Expires>2024-02-02T14:21:00Z</wsu:Expires>
            </wsu:Timestamp>
        </wsse:Security>
    </soapenv:Header>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <niec:xxxxxxxCustLookupRequest>
            <niec:prnNum>819977777770</niec:prNum>
            <niec:versionNumber>1.0</niec:versionNumber>
        </niec:xxxxxxxCustLookupRequest>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I've tried calling Same Service Via SOAP UI tool with same credentials but am getting no error there. Here in POSTMAN I'm getting this error:

```xml
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <env:Header/>
    <env:Body>
        <env:Fault>
            <faultcode>env:Client</faultcode>
            <faultstring> com.sun.xml.wss.impl.WssSoapFaultException: Authentication of Username Password Token Failed; nested exception is com.sun.xml.wss.XWSSecurityException:   com.sun.xml.wss.impl.WssSoapFaultException: Authentication of Username Password Token Failed</faultstring>
        </env:Fault>
    </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

The reason behind this is that when I will be able to call this SOAP service via the POSTMAN then I'll be able to use this XML body to use it as XML String in my Java Code where I'm using REST Template to call this SOAP webservice..

Comment: How are you generating the nonce in postman? Is it the same as how you are doing it in soapui? A nonce has very specific rules on how to generate.

Comment: @tomredfern
As I'm assuming that nonce is just a random number which is to make the request a uniqueness, so I'm using a random number and getting it's base64 code and giving it in the body of POSTMAN request.
Though in code I'm generating it dynamically but here for test purpose I generate the base64 code manually and inserting in body. 

Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Sorry I got confused - did you calculate the password digest using the nonce and created datetime?

Comment: I am not sure how to calculate the password using combination of nonce and created datetime. All I'm using in POSTMAN is shown above.

can you please see above XML body of POSTMAN and let me know If I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a guess, but my suspicion is that you haven't calculated the password digest value to pass in on the field `<wsse:Password />`. My theory is that SoapUI is doing this for you behind the scenes, but in postman you probably need to do it in a pre-request script.

According to the [specification for UsernameToken](https://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/v1.1/wss-v1.1-spec-pr-UsernameTokenProfile-01.htm), the password digest must be calculated according to the following algorithm:

```
Password_Digest = Base64 ( SHA-1 ( nonce + created + password ) )
```

You have to do this because, according to the docs:

> This helps obscure the password and offers a basis for preventing replay attacks

Comment: I am working on this for the first time so not sure how to use password Digest correctly. 
Can you please tell me how I can modify my XML body, specifically the security tag correctly.

Comment: @amarpathak you need to calculate the value to put into the password field. Based on the values in your example request that would be: Base64(SHA-1("ZHNoYmFzZGE5OA==2024-02-01T14:07:00Zpassword")). However the nonce and created datetime strings would obviously be different each time you run it.

Comment: I've tried it and still not able to get response:
I've used a java code to concatenate the value of nonce, created and password. 
Thereafter converting the concatenated value into SHA1 code, 
Thereafter converting the SHA1 code to BASE64 code.
And then using it in PSOTMAN as passwordDigest value
but still same issue